# GPars: return of eachParallel{}

Tags: groovy, gpars

I want to do alot of stuff with each of those example strings and return Object of some other type here Integers, later some bigger class-objects.

Here in this example I am trying something simple, how ever I get a completly wrong result.
At least for what i was hoping to get back. xD

I hoped to get: `[6, 5, 6, 5]` 
but instead I get: `[butter, bread, dragon, table]`

```
package test

@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.0.0')
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

class Test {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>([
        "butter",
        "bread",
        "dragon",
        "table"
    ])

    def closure = { it.length() }

    def doStuff() {
        def results = withPool( 4 ) {
            strings.eachParallel{ it.length()}
        }
        println results
    }

    static main(args) {
        def test = new Test()
        test.doStuff()
    }
}
```

It would be nice if the answer could have a short explanation.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In groovy, `each` (and `eachParallel` in GPars) returns the original collection.

What you want is `collect` (to return the new collection made by calling the closure)

So, change

```
        strings.eachParallel { it.length() }
```

to

```
        strings.collectParallel { it.length() }
```

#### (btw)

GPars now comes bundled with Groovy so you shouldn't need the `@Grab`, and I assume you meant to use your `closure` variable in the `collect`?

```
package test

import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

class Test {
  List<String> strings =  [ "butter", "bread", "dragon", "table" ]

  def closure = { it.length() }

  def doStuff() {
    def results = withPool( 4 ) {
      strings.collectParallel closure
    }
    println results
  }

  static main( args ) {
    def test = new Test()
    test.doStuff()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your reply, your solution works perfectly. Yes I intended to use the closure thanks for the hint!

I know that `GPars` should be included with Groovy.
And as I am using version 2.1, I don't really get why my Groovy/Grails Tool Suite doesn't accept the import without the `@Grab`.
Maybe you have an idea?!

Another question not belonging here(sorry) can I some how give me a more fitting nickname? Couldn't find any settings for it.

Comment: @user2179486 Not sure, I don't use STS, and [does this help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-stack-overflow)?